# Playing Sound with Ubuntu QML Toolkit preview

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, qt5

I've installed the Ubuntu QML Toolkit Preview as per the instructions on http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/ (with a minor fiddle to get it working on 12.04).  I'm trying to write an app that plays a sound file.  Aparrently you can do this using QtMultiMediakit in QtQuick 1, but not in QtQuick 2 as used by the toolkit.

Is it possible to write an app using the toolkit that plays sound?

Comment: Just of interest, which instructions did you follow to install Ubuntu on Nexus 7?

Comment: I'm not sure which part of my post suggests I'm running Ubuntu on a Nexus 7, but I'm not.

Comment: okay, I am looking up to doing that myself, and obviously was too anxious :) But isn't Ubuntu QML toolkit targeted at phones/tablets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved, the answer is to use QtMultimedia 5.0, which now provides the Audio element.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qml-qtmultimedia5-audio.html

Comment: In my case, I seemed to need `libqt5multimedia5-plugins` installed and the SDK didn't pull this in by default.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick example of how to play an mp3 file using [MediaPlayer component from QtMultimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/qml-qtmultimedia5-mediaplayer.html) and the Ubuntu UI toolkit:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

MainView {
    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Simple Player")

        MediaPlayer {
            id: player
            source: "foo.mp3"
            onStatusChanged: {
                if (status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia) {
                    button.pressed = false
                    button.text = i18n.tr("Play")
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            id: button
            text: i18n.tr("Play")
            pressed: false
            onClicked: {
                if (player.playbackState == 1){
                    player.stop()
                    pressed = false
                    text = i18n.tr("Play")
                }
                else{
                    pressed = true
                    text = i18n.tr("Stop")
                    player.play()
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like so:

[image: example player app]