# How do I use qtmultimedia in qml?

Tags: application-development, qml

The link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236619/playing-sound-with-ubuntu-qml-toolkit-preview/236626#236626) says that I should use qtmultimedia 5.0.  Is there a tutorial or example that I can use that shows how to do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what are you trying to do? E.g. play a sound? Use the camera?

Comment: I added an actual example to http://askubuntu.com/questions/236619/playing-sound-with-ubuntu-qml-toolkit-preview/338626#338626

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot to update this saying that I'd figured it out, but the following link is basically how I did it:
[Playing Sound with Ubuntu QML Toolkit preview](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236619/playing-sound-with-ubuntu-qml-toolkit-preview/338626#338626)
Thanks andrewsomething!